# Error compiling Visual Studio 2010 EditorClassifier Extension Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create an Editor Classifier Template project and run it. When I attempt to build I get an error message stating:

"Error trying to read the VSIX manifest file 'extension.vsixmanifest'. Exception has been thrown by target of invocation."

Any thoughts? I've tried googling this but didn't have any luck.

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and the VS 2010 SDK Beta 1.

Thanks,
  Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a matching version of the SDK and the product?  The Beta 1 SDK won't work against anything other than Beta 1 of VS2010.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I am a moron. That fixed it.
Here is the link in case there are any other morons like myself.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en#AdditionalInfo

Comment: Counted my chickens too early. I have both VS2010SP1 and SDK SP1 installed and still get the error.   "... 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Note: in that same directory _is_ a file called Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation.dll

Comment: OK, got it working finally.  Steps:  1. Build the project (error occurs, BUT the output path is still populated with the necessary files).  2. Reset the VS2010SP1 Experimental instance (Start->Programs->[MS VS 2010 SDK SP1]->Tools->"Reset...").  3. Open VS 2010 Exp Instance.  4.  Open Extension Manager, Enable package, Restart.  All this may be unnecessary, but it works. *shrug*

Comment: jberger: that's pretty strange :-/ If you are so inclined, you should [submit a bug on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx).

Comment: @Noah: no matter what (packages) I build, I get that error.  Also, the following is probably related, too:  when I start debugging using "Debug" solution configuration (effectively opening a VS2010 Exp instance), the package is never loaded.  (I've tried the most basic: creating a bare-bones VS Package with all default settings and it still doesn't load.)

I'm going to uninstall all VS2010 stuff, then reinstall just the SP1 stuff and see what happens.

Comment: @Noah: Uninstalled a bunch of VS 2010 stuff (VS2010, SP1, SDK SP1, Silverlight Tools).  Re-installed VS2010, VS2010 SP1, SDK SP1 and now everything seems to be working as it should.  (Note: Silverlight Tools is included with VS2010 SP1).  I'm assuming my issue had to do with my install of the SDK.  I don't remember how I did it, but I'm assuming I just installed SDK SP1 over the top of SDK, which would seem SOP, but is NOT the [correct way](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21835#instructions).  Installer should at least check and give a warning if SDK is installed.